# DataGrip - How to learn any table size in DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

Simple question is that I want to learn table size in DataGrip.Is there any shortcut or a simple way ..

[image]

Comment: Now there is no solution to know it from UI.

Comment: still no solution?

Answer (score 8):

There is now a quick way to do this from the UI.

1. Right click the table of interest
2. Select `Quick documentation`
3. Scroll down to `rows` field

Comment: Such thing doesn't exist inside Quick Documentation

Comment: @Andrew It does, but you have to click _Show table preview_ first, and all it does is run `count(*)` on the table, so you get the row count, not used storage space.

Comment: @AdrianWiik then "Show table preview" must be mentioned inside the answer as one of the steps

Answer (score 5):

This query is a solution:

```
SELECT table_name,
(data_length + index_length) / power(1024, 2) AS tablesize_mb
FROM    information_schema.tables
WHERE   1=1
AND table_name IN ('actor', 'category', 'film', 'film_actor', 'film_category', 'language')
```

Comment: why `1=1` is necessary in `WHERE` condition?

Comment: It's not necessary but it's a common and quick way to easily comment out the AND clause while debugging the query

Answer (score 1):

Table size is available as of v 2022.2.2 (see comment + ticket [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4281/Show-physical-table-size-in-table-documentation#focus=Comments-27-6339249.0-0))

Similar to softmax55's answer:

1. Right click the table
2. Select `Quick documentation`
3. Scroll down & select `Show table preview`
4. Row count, data size, and index size are now available (see [sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yX8b.png))